# Expose kafka stream metrics with spring actuator (prometheus)

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-boot-actuator

I am running a Kafka Stream app with Springboot 2.

I would like to have my kafka stream metrics available in the prometheus format at `host:8080/actuator/prometheus`

I don't manage to have this. I am not sure I understand how kafka stream metrics are exported.
Can `actuator` get these JMX metrics ?
Is there a way to get these metrics and expose them in Prometheus format ?

PS: didn't worked with java jmx_prometheus_agent neither

Does someone has a solution or an example ?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You could produce all available Kafka-Streams metrics (the same as from `KafkaStreams.metrics()`) into `Prometheus` using `micrometer-core` and `spring-kafka` libraries. For integrating Kafka-Streams with `micrometer`, you could have [KafkaStreamsMicrometerListener](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/main/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/streams/KafkaStreamsMicrometerListener.java) bean:

```
@Bean 
KafkaStreamsMicrometerListener kafkaStreamsMicrometerListener(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) { 
    return new KafkaStreamsMicrometerListener(meterRegistry); 
}
```

where `MeterRegistry` is from `micrometer-core` dependency.

If you create Kafka Streams using `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean` from `spring-kafka`, then you need to add listener into it:

```
streamsBuilderFactoryBean.addListener(kafkaStreamsMicrometerListener);
```

And if you create `KafkaStreams` objects directly, then on each `KafkaStreams` object you need to invoke

```
kafkaStreamsMicrometerListener.streamsAdded(beanId, kafkaStreams);
```

where `beanId` is any unique identifier per `KafkaStreams` object.

As a result, Kafka Streams provides multiple useful Prometheus metrics, like `kafka_consumer_coordinator_rebalance_latency_avg`, `kafka_stream_thread_task_closed_rate`, etc. `KafkaStreamsMicrometerListener` under the hood uses [KafkaStreamsMetrics](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/main/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/kafka/KafkaStreamsMetrics.java).

If you need to have Grafana Prometheus graphs with these metrics, you need to add them as [Gauge metric type](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#gauge).

Comment: this is for spring application, how to do it for a plain java application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a complete example, but metrics are well accessible and documented in Confluent documentation on [Monitoring Kafka Streams](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/monitoring.html).

Maybe dismiss actuator and use `@RestController` from Spring Web along with `KafkaStreams#metrics()` to publish exactly what you need.